# Understanding value category of functions in C++

Tags: c++

First of all, I have read through this [article](http://bajamircea.github.io/coding/cpp/2016/04/07/move-forward.html), explaining the functionalities of `std::move` and `std::forward`. In that post, there is an example code snippet as follows which I use in my test.

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> commands;

template<typename ftor>
void install_command(std::string name, ftor && handler)
{
  commands.insert({
    std::move(name),
    std::forward<ftor>(handler)
  });
}
```

As I want to experiment on the actual usage, I have written a simple piece of code as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

// code copied from above goes here

void fnA() { cout << "Function A." << endl; }
function<void()> fnB = [&]() -> void {
    cout << "Function B." << endl;
}

void RunTest() {
    install_command("#1", fnA);
    install_command("#2", move(fnA));
    install_command("#3", fnB);
    //install_command("#4", move(fnB));

    fnA();
    fnB();

    for (const auto& p : commands) {
        cout << p.first.c_str() << ": " << &p.second << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    RunTest();
    return 0;
}
```

The program is compiled with `-std=c++11`, and the execution result is as follows.

```
Function A.
Function B.
#1: 0xaf8088
#2: 0xaf8018
#3: 0xaf81a8
```

If I uncomment the line `install_command("#4", move(fnB));`, there is a runtime error.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'
  what():  bad_function_call
Function A.
```

I believe the ownership of the lambda function has been transferred from `function<void()> fnB` to `commands["#4"]`, but why does `fnA()` work while `fnB()` does not?

Comment: `fnA` is a function and `fnB` is a `std::function` object. `fnA` can never lose 'ownership' as it isn't an object. I.E: you're implicitly calling the ctor of `std::function` when you pass `fnA`

Comment: @Neijwiert Can I say `std::function` is a wrapper of function, and when `install_command("#1", fnA);` is run, the copy constructor of `std::function` kicks in and makes a copy of the function `fnA`, then being inserted to `commands`?

Comment: `std::function` is not per say a wrapper of just functions. When you pass `fnA` you're not calling the copy constructor, but you're calling `template< class F > 
function( F f );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fnA` is a regular function not a `std::function` as `fnB`

When you do

```
commands.insert({
    std::move(name),
    std::forward<ftor>(handler)
})
```

You create

- `std::function<void()>` from `void(&)()` for `fnA`
- `std::function<void()>` from `void(&)()` for `std::move(fnA)`
- `std::function<void()>` from `std::function<void()>&` for `fnB` (so copy constructor)
- `std::function<void()>` from `std::function<void()>&&` for `std::move(fnB)` (so move constructor)

Only the later modify input argument.